# Accessing Grandparent's variable

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an Object with the variable "parentVar", and I want to write the response of an ajax-request into it.
Sounds easy, but I'm not able to do this, due to some namespace-troubles.

I wrote a very minimalistic example, which shows the problem.

The ajax-request will be started, when I call the Object's init-Function:

```
var parentObj = new Parent();
//Do some work (I need some functionality from the object before it can be fully initialized)
alert("Old Value = " + parentObj.parentVar);
parentObj.init(function(){
    alert("New Value = " + parentObj.parentVar);
});
```

The init-Function calls the Function "load" which performs an Ajax-Request, and returns the received data (in another callback-Function).

```
function Parent(){
    this.parentVar = "old";                 //this value should be replaced

    this.init = function(initCallBack){

        this.load(function(newData){        //load the content of the file
            this.parentVar = newData;       //write the content into the variable
            initCallBack();                 //I'm done!
        });

    }

    this.load = function(callbackFunc){
        //load the new value from a file via ajax (asyncron).
        //When finished: call callbackFunc
        callbackFunc("newValue");
    }
}
```

I already tried passing the scope to the loader-function, and getting it back in the callBack-Function. But it didn't work.

I also tried "`var parentscope = this;`" in the init-Function, 
and "`parentscope.parentVar = newData;`" - it didn't work either.

Is it possible to achieve this with parentVar being private? (I mean "`var parentVar = 'old';`" instead of "`this.parentVar = 'old';`").

Comment: @Chandranshu: Yes, it's getting called. And the variable "newData" contains the correct content.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get 2 alerts, both telling me that the value "old" is in the variable

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if you need any explanations.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers below so that this question will be removed from the User's question stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function passed to `load()` doesn't have the value of `this` that you want. The way you call that function `this` will be `window`. You can bind the value of `this` as follows:

```
    this.load(function(newData){        //load the content of the file
        this.parentVar = newData;       //write the content into the variable
        initCallBack();                 //I'm done!
    }.bind(this));
```

...and then it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/v9Hvb/

> *Is it possible to achieve this with `parentVar` being private? (I mean `var parentVar = 'old';` instead of `this.parentVar = 'old';`).*

You can use a private variable inside the `Parent()` constructor and it will be accessible within all of the methods defined inside the constructor. But it *won't* be accessible outside with `parentObj.parentVar` so you'd have to add a getter method.

It would be easier to use a private `var self = this;` variable inside the `Parent()` constructor and then use `self` instead of `this` in the methods:

```
function Parent(){
    var self = this;
    self.parentVar = "old";                 //this value should be replaced
    self.init = function(initCallBack){    
        self.load(function(newData){        //load the content of the file
            self.parentVar = newData;       //write the content into the variable
            initCallBack();                 //I'm done!
        });

    }    
    self.load = function(callbackFunc){
        //load the new value from a file via ajax (asyncron).
        //When finished: call callbackFunc
        callbackFunc("newValue");
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9Hvb/1/

Further reading: [MDN's `this` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `this` within the callback passed to the load within the init function doesn't refer to the `Parent` object but the `window` object. There is a well known hack for this: save the reference to the Parent's `this` in `_this`. Other variable names commonly used are `that` and `self` and all these prefixed with more underscores. Here is a code that works:

```
function Parent(){
    this.parentVar = "old";                 //this value should be replaced
    var _this = this;
    this.init = function(initCallBack){

        this.load(function(newData){        //load the content of the file
            _this.parentVar = newData;       //write the content into the variable
            initCallBack();                 //I'm done!
        });

    }

    this.load = function(callbackFunc){
        //load the new value from a file via ajax (asyncron).
        //When finished: call callbackFunc
        callbackFunc("newValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: _"the `this` within the `init` function doesn't refer to the Parent object"_ - Yes it does. It also does within the `.load()` function. But `this` is not the parent object within the callback.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mean what I wanted it to mean. I was talking about the `this` in the callback passed to the load. I guess we meant the same thing but your description is much more clearer.